# What is the number of iteration needed for the message passing algorithm to converge when applied to a tanner graph (factor graph)?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, statistical-inference, machine-learning

I understand that the message passing algorithm (Belief Propagation algorithm), when applied to a factor graph, (tanner graph, bipartite graph) consists in an exchange in messages between the factor nodes and the variable nodes, these messages keep being updated until a certain number of iterations where we reach convergence. And here is my question:
What is the number of iterations needed for the message passing algorithm to converge when applied to a tanner graph (factor graph)?
Is there some conditions for the convergence to happen? if yes, what are these conditions?
I am not using a loopy graph, my graph is very simple, it is an acyclic bipartite graph, tanner graph.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A "loopy" graph in this context is any graph which has cycles, and Tanner graphs typically do have cycles. (Also, I sure don't see the connection between Tanner graphs and belief propagation.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov i am applying the message passing algorithm on a factor graph (there are no cycles, it is a bipartite graph) , my aim is to know the number of iterations needed for the algorithm to converge

Comment: You keep emphasizing it being a bipartite graph, but lots of bipartite graphs do have cycles! Any even cycle is bipartite.

Comment: @MishaLavrov you are right, but the graph i am talking about does not have cycles (acyclic graphs). Then what is the number of iterations needed for the algorithm to converge? and what are the conditions for convergence in this case?